# How to check for the AlternationCount within a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

For my `DataGrid` I created a `DataTemplate`:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
     <Label>Test</Label>
  </DataTemplate>
```

This `DataTemplate` will be used for a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. The `DataGrid` has an `AlternationCount = 2` property.

I want to check the current `AlternationCount` within my `DataTemplate` to set the content depending on the `AlternationCount`. How can I ask for the `AlternationCount`?

**Update 1:**

I tried the suggestion of Sheridan with the following code:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Label">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Using this style within my `DataTemplate` as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
  <Label x:Name="MyLabel" Style={StaticResource MyStyle}">Test</Label>
</DataTemplate>
```

But unfortunately, only the red background appears. it seems to me that the `AlternationIndex` is constantly 0. What am I missing here?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to read the value of an attached property that was (indirectly) set on a `DataGridRow` from a `Label` in a cell in that row. However normally, it is possible to use a `RelativeSource Binding` to reach the `DataGridRow` object, but for some reason, that does not work for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to access the [`AlternationCount` attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), although I think that you actually need the [`AlternationIndex` attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. Essentially, you can access the value of this attached property in XAML in a `Trigger`, like this:

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

The `TargetType` of your `Style` should not be set to `Label`. It should be set to the container of the data, eg. a ComboBoxItem, ListBoxItem, etc. In your case, you should set your `Style TargetType` to `DataGridRow`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you set the `x:Key` value of the `Style`, let's say you call it `RowStyle`, then you can set that `Style` as the `DataGrid.RowStyle` property value:

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}" ... />
```

If you don't set the `x:Key` value of the `Style` and it is in scope of the `DataGrid`, then it will implicitly be applied.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it, but the red color will not appear. It seems to me, that the AlternationIndex is constantly 0. See my Update for details.

Comment: Thank you again for your Update. I really appreciate your help. Setting the target type to DataGridRow will affect the whole row to change the background color. What I want is to only change the background color in the DataTemplate (i.e. the DataGridCell) itself, not for the whole row. That is why I am asking to access the AlternationIndex in the DataTemplate, so I could just set the background of the label. Is there a way to achieve this, too?

Comment: Why do I waste so much of my time answering questions that the question authors haven't even bothered to provide essential information for? Frankly, I'm surprised that someone with your reputation would omit such essential information from your question.

Comment: I'm to blame for my misleading question - sorry. Should have taken more time to make a more clear and precise description of my problem.